# About riscv64-unknown-elf

Tags: riscv

I am new to rocket chip,
and I want to ask question.
where can I know what these command can do?
I already knew gcc(c compiler) and objdump(generate assembly code).
what others can do?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard Linux documentation. So take the name after the common **riscv64-unknown-elf** prefix and look it up in the manual. Eg...

```
man as
man ld
man objdump
man run
...etc...
```